# Proof that $a\mid x, b\mid x, \gcd(a,b)=1 \implies (ab)\mid x$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

I need to prove that:

$$a\mid x, b\mid x, \gcd(a,b)=1 \implies (ab)\mid x$$

What I thought was:

$$a\mid x \implies x = aq_1\\b\mid x\implies x = bq_1$$

Also, since $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, we have that

$$am+bn=1$$ for some integers $m,n$.

I need to work with it somehow so I can conclude that

$$x = (ab)k$$

for some $k$.

I can't see anyome from here. Could you guys give me some help?

Comment: try the Prime Factorization theorem

Comment: More generally, $a,b\mid n\iff \text{lcm}(a,b)\mid n$

Comment: I think you mean $q_2$.

Comment: let $x/a=\alpha, b/x=\beta$, then $x/(ab) = \alpha\beta$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note the following

$$am+bn=1 \implies axm +bxn=x$$
$$abq_1m+baq_2n=x$$
$$ab(q_1m+q_2n)=x$$

i.e., $ab|x$.

Comment: This is the correct solution (In the sense you can use it later when you're in more general structures)

Comment: Simple, and elegant. +1

Answer (score 2):

Well, we know that $a|x$ and $b|x$. But we also know that $gcd(a,b) = 1$. So that means that $a$ and $b$ do not share any factors. But by the statements above, some set of primes $p_1p_2p_3\ldots p_n k = x$ and $g_1g_2\ldots g_t y = x $ where $p_1p_2\ldots p_n = a$ and $g_1g_2\ldots g_t = b$. The result follows.

Comment: This was my immediate first thought. However I chose the alternative sense unique factorization into primes isn't always guaranteed after I saw the abstract algebra tag.

Comment: @Eoin What do you mean by not guaranteed?

Comment: Say, for instance, in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-5}]$ we have $2\times 3 = (1+\sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5})$ is a factorization into irreducibles and not unique. But then maybe bezout's identity wouldn't have appeared either... anyways +1

Comment: @Eoin I think $gcd$ is a term for integers only right?

Comment: No, gcd can be defined to arbitrary commutative rings.

Comment: @Eoin ok, even so, I believe we are still dealing with integers in this context.

Comment: Me too. So I like your solution.

Comment: @Eoin Thanks. It looks like your solution is more techinical, but mine is more intuitive. You just boosted my mood again, following my excitement by achiveing 1000 rep :).